# Get image URL from media library in input

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, jquery, templates

On `wp-admin/post.php?post=447&action=edit` for example I have a link and an input.

The link appears as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="button insert-media add_media" data-editor="tj_image_url" >gallery</a>
```

When I click the link the media library opens, and i'd like the URL of the inserted image to populate an input field, eg.

```
<input type="text" name="tj_image_url" id="tj_image_url" value="VALUEHERE" size="30" />
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a way to generate the attachment ID when inserting the image. You can then use the attachment ID to populate the input value. Are you not talking about an on-page input field?

Try something like this:

```
<?php 
//First get the attachment ID
$attachment_id = 8;
?>

<input type="text" name="tj_image_url" id="tj_image_url" value="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: I am assuming you have a way to generate the attachment ID when inserting the image. You can then use the attachment ID to populate the input value. Are you not talking about an on-page input field?

Comment: Next time you should [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/142468/edit) your answer and add your extra info to that

Answer (score 1):

You can get by post page id

```
if (has_post_thumbnail($page_id) ):
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($page_id), 'page-post-thumbnail' );
   endif;   
   $image_URI = $image[0];
```

echo `$image_URI` inside image `src`.